# Using only autolayout (no initwithframe), configure accessoryview button for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uikit

I've found lots of questions about this, but they all use initWithFrame. Is there any way to do it strictly using autolayout?

I've tried setting the accessoryview to the button and adding constraints to the cell, and adding the button as a subview of the accessory view and adding constraints to the accessory view. Here's my most promising attempt:

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
cell.accessoryView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:button];
NSDictionary *varDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button);
[cell.accessoryView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[button]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:varDict]];
[cell.accessoryView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[button]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:varDict]];
```

It keeps telling me that it can't parse the constraint, because the related view doesn't have a superview. I called addSubview! What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to disable the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for the `cell.accessoryView`, because you want to keep the layout of the `accessoryView` within the `cell`, right? If yes, you should remove this line:

```
cell.accessoryView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can add the button as a subview of accessoryview.
But I've set the button as the accessoryview and after that, I've called sizeToFit on the button. It worked for me.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[button setTitle: @"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cell.accessoryview = button;
[button sizeToFit];
```

Swift version:

```
var button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
cell.accessoryview = button
button.sizeToFit()
```

Hope this will help someone.